# Different time use core/date

Tags: date

i tried to reformat date and time in magento.

from 
`$order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()`

i can get result =  Feb 22, 2015 6:44:52 PM, but when i tried to reformat using this code

```
Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:i', strtotime($order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()));
```

i get result = 2015-02-22 10:44

i dont know what's wrong with it, please give me any advice.

thank you

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using wrong date format in argument of function

use below format to get your desired out put

```
echo Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('M d, Y h:m:s', strtotime('2013-02-19 17:26:37'));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Feb 19, 2013 18:02:37
```

Hope this will sure work for you.

Comment: @elune, hope my answer is sure useful to u. pls dont forget to acpt and vot up so some can use it for future

Answer (score 0):

That's because dates are always stored as UTC in the database, this is the raw value of the attribute, that you get with `$order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()`

The `core/date` model converts it to the store timezone. This is usually the desired behavior and the reason, you should always use the Magento methods to output dates.